# maven ошибка при запуске no main manifest attribute

Tags: java, javafx, maven, jar

Попробовал собрать первое для себя приложение на javafx с помощью maven 
Запустил через `java -jar` и падает ошибка

> no main manifest attribute

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Diploma</groupId>
    <artifactId>Diploma</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>

                    <mainClass>sample.MainApp</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ghost4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>ghost4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
        <mainClass>com.mypackage.MyClass</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: На попфтку добавить archive, maven говорит мне elemnt archive is not allowed here и так для всех добавленных вами тегов